# What's the Context-Free grammar of this language :L= {a^n b^m c^p d^q / m+n=p+q where n,m,p,q >=0 }

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I was trying to find the context-free grammar of
 `L= {a^n b^m c^p d^q / m+n=p+q where n,m,p,q >=0 }` but I'm stuck.
This is what I did so far:

```
S -> X S Y | epsilon
X -> a|b
Y -> c|d
```

but I figured out that it doesn't respect the order, for example `bacd` is accepted but it shouldn't:

```
X S Y -> XX S YY -> ba S cd -> bacd
```

Comment: I suspect this is really a question for [cs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can "force" the order using the following "trick":

```
  S -> aSd |  X | Y
  X -> bXd | Z
  Y -> aYc | Z
  Z -> bZc | epsilon
```

Basically, we allow `S` to only derive `a`'s and `d`'s (the "outer" part of a fully derived word). Then, we allow `S` to derive either `X` or `Y`, each of them representing a change: we start to write `b`'s instead of `a`'s or start using `c`'s instead of `d`'s (this is the second-innermost part of a fully derived word), and finally `Z` allows only `b`'s and `c`'s (which is the innermost part of a fully derived word)

Answer (score 2):

S -> aSd to put A’s and d’s on both sides.

S -> X | Y  - X produces more A’s, Y more d’s

X -> aXc  - to have more A’s than d’s

Y -> bYd  - to have more d’s than a’s

X -> Z. - Z adds b and c

Y -> Z - Z adds b and c

Z -> bZc  Z adds b and c

Z -> eps Z disappears at last.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)